# Scroll to left-most element on window resize - how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, window

I'm a bit of a jQuery newbie, only recently started.

I am using http://flesler.blogspot.com.au/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html (Ariel Flesler's scrollTo plugin)

it's a horizontal scrolling website.

I'm trying to scroll to the element which is closest to the left side of the window when the window gets resized.

I can only seem to be able to get it to scroll to the first element in the array, so when I resize the window, no matter where the window is, the window scrolls to the first ".example" in the flow.

**Update:** I've made some progress, I've added a new variable to calculate how far has been scrolled. now i seem to need a way to find out what the lowest value of the loop is to use in my "if" statement as it seems to want to jump from one element to the next or none at all.

the `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined` was due to the value of the scrollTo being negative (you can't scroll below 0 as 0 is the beginning of your document) so to fix this i added the value of how much has been scrolled so far, and then added whatever value element_position had to calculate correctly.

**Update 2:** there was a problem with my mathematics, the question has been updated to reflect the solution. only problem now is that it's a fluid layout, so using fixed values like "70" in my if statement tend to break it after a certain point.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).resize(function() {
      $('.example').each(function(index) {
          var example = $(this);
          var scroll_position = $('#container').scrollLeft();
      var element_position = example.offset().left;

          if (element_position < 70 && position > -70) {
              $('#container').scrollTo(scroll_position + element_position);
          }
      });
   });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="example"></div>
   <div class="example"></div>
   <div class="example"></div>
   <div class="example"></div>
   <div class="example"></div>
   <div class="example"></div>
</div>
```

I also recieve the following error

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
```

Comment: `if (position = 100)` should be `if(position == 100)`, otherwise it'll always evaluate true. Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but that may get you closer.

Comment: Yes sorry, haha, I'm very tired! accidentally pasted the code wrong. It is supposed to be `if (position <= 100)`

Comment: are you looking for the left most element visible, or the left most element that is completely on the screen? I.e., if an .example were 20% visible, would you scroll left to fully see it, or right to fully hide it?

Comment: Hi chris, thanks for responding - I seem to have worked the issue out, there was some problem with my mathematics. I've updated my question to reflect the solution.To answer your question - yes I was looking for it to scroll to the futhermost left div, even if it was only 20% visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).resize(function() {
      var scroll_position = $('#container').scrollLeft();
      $('.example').each(function() {
          var example = $(this);
          var left = example.offset().left;
          var right = left + example.width();

          if (right > 0) {
              $('#container').scrollTo(scroll_position + left);
              return false;
          }
      });
   });
});​
```

checks for the first element in the selected elements that has its right border in the viewport..

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response, the coding seems solid - and when expanding the window it works fine, but for some reason when contracting the window, it jumps around the place (it's a fluid layout and the dimensions of the element are changing, hence this script in the first place.)

Comment: if element dimensions change animated the script might be called too early, before elements are ready..

Comment: the function is called within `$(document).ready(function(){`. when I say the element changes dimensions, I mean the CSS applied to the div is a percentile width which is relative to the window width (which changes size depending on the size of the window)

Comment: Unfortunately I think the skipping is inherent with the browser. If you resize it too fast, it jumps all over the place. I changed the if statement, and it seems to give it some leeway in terms of being able to contract, if you do it slowly. I'm going to mark up this answer as correct as it is a clean solution to 99% of the problem.